# How can I add the value of an item in a list box to a local variable in C#?

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox, listboxitems

So I'm doing a practical that involves asking the user to input a score between `0` and `100`. The program will keep track of the number of scores that have been entered, the total score (sum of all scores) and the average score.

To calculate the total score, I've come up of the idea of using a for loop that will cycle through my listbox and add each score to a variable (below).

```
int sTotal = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lstScores.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //Calculation occurs here
}
txtScoreTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sTotal);
```

Thing is, I don't exactly know how to do it. I've tried searching to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Mong Zhu, I was indeed a little bit too fast, I deleted my comment and supplied the answer which I think is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int sTotal = 0;
    int Average = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lstScores.Items.Count; i++)
    {
         bool result = Int16.TryParse(lstScores.Items[i],out int res);
         if (result)
         {
            sTotale += res;        
         }
    }
    Average = sTotal / lstScores.Items.Count;
    txtScoreTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sTotal);
```

Comment: What is `int16`?

Comment: You can call TryParse method writing Int16, so if the conversion goes bad you can handle the exception with a simply else

Comment: I meant that you wrote `int16`, not `Int16`. But I was also curious why you are using that instead of `Int32`, which is what `int` is an alias for.

Comment: oh I changed int16, to Int16, was wrong sorry, but i don't know why i should use Int32 instead Int16

Comment: Well an Int16 is relatively tiny, so you can only accurately parse numbers up to 32,767. Int32 max value is 2,147,483,647 and is normally what is used. That's why `int` is an alias for `Int32`, which you're using everywhere else. In general you should just use the alias.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is it to do with a foreach loop like this:

```
        int sTotal = 0;
        foreach (string item in lstScores.Items)
        {
            sTotal += Int32.Parse(item);
        }
        txtScoreTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sTotal);
```

Comment: if you supply an answer, may be you could teach a little fishing.. instead of simply feeding fish ;)

Comment: For very basic questions I usually don't provide that since it is most often I can't find the correct method question or a lack of basic knowledge. Supplying the correct method does not need any specification and for lack of basic knowledge (perfectly acceptable for beginning programmers) I can't address that in a single answer. I just provide the solution and the key words to google for future reference.

Comment: to cite the [How do I write a good answer? Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." IMHO, if such simple things are asked then the lack of basic knowledge ( which is the basis of understanding given code) actually prevents someone of grasping the "why it actually works" without any explanation. But it's your answer. Feel free

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
int i = 0, result = 0;
while (i < lstScores.Items.Count)
{
   result += Convert.ToInt32(lstScores.Items[i++]);
}

txtScoreTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

I havent tried following, but you can try 1 line solution too

```
var sum = lstScores.Items.OfType<object>().Sum(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

> You need to handle exception if sum exceedes `int.Max`